# Need Help converting JavaObject To Json in Generic Pattern

Tags: java, json, algorithm, spring-boot, generics

I wrote a Generic method which works fine converting any Json object to Generic Object.

```
public <T> T convertJsontoObject    (String jsonObj, Class<T> any Type)
             throws JsonMappingException, JsonProcessingException 
             {
           ObjectMapper objectMap = new ObjectMapper();
              return objectMap.readValue(jsonObj, any Type);

              }
```

But has an issue while converting the Generic Object type to JSON format with the below code format. Would someone help me or guide me with related code.. I am not sure how to retain an Object from Generic class type as the method doesn't support for generic and I want to have a Generic method to perform the conversions....

```
 public <T> String convertObjectToJson(Class<T> anyType) 
               { String jsonStringObj = ""; 
                try { jsonStringObj = new 
               ObjectMapper().writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(anyType);}
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you return a String you don't need to use generics and you can receive only an Object on methods

```java
// you can treate try and catch inside them as you prefer

public static <T> T fromJson(String json, Class<T> classToReturn) throws Exception{
    return  new ObjectMapper().readValue(json, classToReturn);
}

public static String toJson(Object obj) throws Exception{
    return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
}

public static String toJsonPrettyNonNullTreatingDateTypes(Object obj) throws Exception{
    return  new ObjectMapper()
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL)
            .setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY)
            .registerModule(new JavaTimeModule() );
            .writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
            .writeValueAsString(obj);
}
```

using them

```java
MyObject obj = fromJson(jsonString, MyObject.class );

String json = toJson(new MyObject()); //  Object can accept any types

String json = toJsonPrettyNonNullTreatingDateTypes(new MyObject());
```

Comment: Thanks! Now that method works for any Class Object. I actually spent hours trying to write a Generic method which would work for any class type. One other quick question, How would I be able to create/retain an Object of any Runtime time Class stored in "classToReturn" type in Generics.

Comment: don't forget to mark your question as answered as you prefer. about your question `create object in runtime` this will help you `MyObject.class.getDeclaredConstructor().newInstance()` to create a instance or your class. try to found about reflections in java